Japanese businesses checking for landing sticker
First time traveling to Japan and so far I've had exactly two encounters with private businesses that asked to see my passport.
The first was a private clinic we visited for a broken foot (long story, not interesting).
The second was Toyota rent-a-car.
Completely understandable that they would both request to see some identification, and when faced with an obvious foreigner a passport is the obvious document to ask for.
What I found peculiar was they both flipped through the visa pages looking for the landing permission sticker, which I took it to mean "let's check if this guy is here legally".
Now I am wondering if a certain class of Japanese businesses are deputized by the state to act as frontline immigration agents. To be clear: I don't have a problem with the behavior, but found it intriguing. I have never seen a private business do this in any other country.
Any theories?

If you are a temporary visitor to Japan, you can also make tax-free purchases in participating stores, and for that purpose the seller needs access to your landing sticker in your passport, its not migration control at all, but just checking if you actually qualify for the tax-free purchase.

If they were actually looking for illegals, this would be a very ineffective choice of businesses... Undocumented immigrants in Japan generally make a living out of either hard labor (esp. construction & agriculture) or petty crime, and neither class would be likely to rent cars or visit private clinics...

"wondering if a certain class of Japanese businesses are deputized by the state to act as frontline immigration agents" The simple answer is no, they were just checking how long you've been there (both explained in the answers).

@Dr.Snoopy you buy tax-free in the shop? When I purchased "tax-free"  (twice and not in Japan) I paid with the tax and when leaving the country I got a refund (after going to the right pace at the airport with the paperwork of the shop - which just listed the taxes in details)

@WoJ In Japan is in the shop directly, that was my experience 2018-2019.

@Dr.Snoopy ah interesting, so they indeed need to be trained on all the details. This was quite surprising because it meant that all shops must have such people, or that you can only buy tax-free in some shops. (as opposed to buying in a shop, getting some generic tax breakdown and having a specialized person at the airport making sure you can buy tax free)

@WoJ Only some shops have this, that is why I said "participating stores".

Question 1: This has to do with Japan's universal healthcare system.
Japan has a (quasi-)single-payer healthcare system (every long-term resident of Japan is required by law to be a member of a healthcare mutual insurance. Technically there are multiple insurers, but all of them provide the exact same benefits).
Also, all Japanese healthcare providers, private or public, charge the same price. These prices are fixed by the Ministry of Health, Labor and Welfare (MHLW). Thanks to these laws which heavily regulate the healthcare industry, the Japanese healthcare system is able to provide high level care at one of the lowest rates globally. However, this does not apply to temporary visitors who are not by law required to and eligible to be insured under the national health insurance scheme. They could legally be charged more, often 2 or 3 times the mandated price.
Therefore, they are just checking your passport to make sure that you indeed are a foreign visitor (uninsured), and to make sure that you will pay your medical fees. First of all, they want to make sure that it is OK to provide service to you at the higher price. Also, normally, if you fail to make the payment (30% copay for insured individuals) upfront, most clinics and hospitals will let you go, as they can always be reimbursed by your insurer either sue you in a summary court, or ask your insurer to collect it for them. However, it is impossible to do so if you are a temporary visitor ineligible to be insured (you can just leave the country), and the government recommends copying your passport in this case so that you don't just dash without consequences.
Question 2: as the other answers have said, IDPs are only valid for use in Japan within 1 year of your entry to Japan. If you need to drive longer, you will need to obtain a Japanese driver's license. Therefore, they must check your entry stamp if you show them an IDP. They cannot rent you a vehicle if beyond the law-mandated 1 year validity period.

Foreign licenses are valid in Japan for a maximum of one year from the date of entry. For Toyota Rent a Car to confirm if your IDP/license is valid, they must confirm you are within one year of your entry to Japan as a visitor.
https://rent.toyota.co.jp/global_eng/drive/

This only answers half of the question.

In a word, no, there isn't any class of Japanese business that is deputized by the state to act as frontline immigration agents. You are required to present your passport when checking in at hotels, and passports are the only form of foreign ID accepted by businesses that need ID (like your two examples of rental cars and medical clinics), but they are not responsible for your visa status. JNTO:

According to the Ministry of Health, Labour and Welfare, "Since April 1, 2005, under the relevant laws and regulations, the Japanese Government is requiring 'foreign nationals who do not possess an address in Japan' to provide their nationality and passport number in addition to their name, address, and occupation, etc. and produce and make a copy of their passport upon checking in at lodgings."

The underlying regulation underlines that technically the only pieces of information they need are your nationality and passport number:

３． 　旅券の写しの保存について
今般の改正に伴う厚生労働省健康局長通知により、宿泊者名簿の記載の正確を期するため、国籍及び旅券番号を記載していただく宿泊者の方については、その方の旅券の写しの保存をお願いしておりますので、御理解と御協力をお願いいたします。

The charitable interpretation for your case is that they want to check if you're a long-term resident who has local health insurance coverage, but if you were you'd be presenting a zairyu card, not a passport. So likely they're just a combination clueless, overly cautious, or following some long-obsolete guidance.

While this applies to lodgings (with the requirement to note the nationality and passport number and make a copy), it does not mean there isn’t a separate regulation requiring other types of businesses to make other checks. Difficult as ever to prove a negative, though.

One possibility is they are using it as a polite way of checking if they should be prompting you for your zairyu card if you are a resident who hasn't fully got their head around the system.

"but if you were you'd be presenting a zairyu card, not a passport" - For clinics you would present your health insurance card (be it national or through your company), but as of December (I believe), you will have to present your MyNumber card.
